# SQL Server, group by xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a data set with something like

```
select * 
from
    (select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_1'c3,'v4_asd'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_2'c3,'v4_fds'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_3'c3,'v4_gfd'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_2'c2,'v3_4'c3,'v4_234'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_2'c2,'v3_5'c3,'v4_654'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_6'c3,'v4_hgf'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_7'c3,'v4_ttr'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_3'c2,'v3_8'c3,'v4_654'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_3'c2,'v3_9'c3,'v4_t54'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_4'c2,'v3_0'c3,'v4_43e'c4) t
```

I want to group by c1, c2 and have c3, c4 on a xml.

I tried

```
select *
into #t
from 
    (select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_1'c3,'v4_asd'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_2'c3,'v4_fds'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_3'c3,'v4_gfd'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_2'c2,'v3_4'c3,'v4_234'c4 union all
     select 'v1_1'c1,'v2_2'c2,'v3_5'c3,'v4_654'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_6'c3,'v4_hgf'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_1'c2,'v3_7'c3,'v4_ttr'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_3'c2,'v3_8'c3,'v4_654'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_3'c2,'v3_9'c3,'v4_t54'c4 union all
     select 'v1_2'c1,'v2_4'c2,'v3_0'c3,'v4_43e'c4) t


select 
    *,
    (select c3, c4 
     from #t t2 
     where t.c2 = t2.c2 
       and t.c1 = t2.c1 
     for xml path(''))
from 
    #t t
```

but I'm looking to not use distinct or max in group by to keep only one value.

i used this solution

```
select *,
       (select * from #t i1 where t1.c1=i1.c1 and t1.c2=i1.c2 for xml raw)
from (select distinct c1,c2 from #t) t1
```

instead create multiple xml and group them, i distinct before the key and create only the xml are needed

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here. Could you post what your expect result would look like?

Comment: "group by . . . on a xml" ???  What does that mean?

Comment: You've now posted what you've tried, which is great, but what we need to know is what you want it to look like, if you what you tried isn't correct.

Comment: We need to know what your expected results are for your Sample data. Provided Sample data and expected results for different data isn't going to help us. Have a look at [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` allows you to avoid `DISTINCT` which cannot return the XML as a typed column (and is rather slow with larger sets).

```
SELECT
     a.c1
    ,a.c2
    ,(
        SELECT b.c3
              ,b.c4
        FROM #t AS b
        WHERE a.c1 = b.c1
          AND a.c2 = b.c2
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    )
FROM #t AS a
GROUP BY a.c1, a.c2
```

The result

```
c1      c2      TheXML
v1_1    v2_1    <c3>v3_1</c3><c4>v4_asd</c4><c3>v3_2</c3><c4>v4_fds</c4><c3>v3_3</c3><c4>v4_gfd</c4>
v1_1    v2_2    <c3>v3_4</c3><c4>v4_234</c4><c3>v3_5</c3><c4>v4_654</c4>
v1_2    v2_1    <c3>v3_6</c3><c4>v4_hgf</c4><c3>v3_7</c3><c4>v4_ttr</c4>
v1_2    v2_3    <c3>v3_8</c3><c4>v4_654</c4><c3>v3_9</c3><c4>v4_t54</c4>
v1_2    v2_4    <c3>v3_0</c3><c4>v4_43e</c4>
```

With indexe(s) on c1 and c2 this should be pretty fast.